# How to access raw.githubusercontent.com on Github for Enterprise?

Tags: github, repository

I'm trying to create a helm chart repo on our enterprise's Github. 
As suggested in [this link](https://hackernoon.com/using-a-private-github-repo-as-helm-chart-repo-https-access-95629b2af27c), I should get access to something similar to `raw.githubusercontent.com` on our Github. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find your GitHub Enterprise instance's raw URL, just navigate to any file in your Enterprise repository and click the `Raw` button to see its Raw URL. Just don't forget to truncate the authorization token from the URL so it looks something like this:

https://raw.github.company.com/User_Or_OrgName/Branch_Or_Commit_ID/file_name.file_extension